# When I add toString method it shows me an error message

Tags: java

When I add the toString method, my code shows me this message:

> Error message: cannot create method implementation, Reasone
>   JavaVirtualMachien is not in build path

While I have JavaVirtualMachiens and I have been use toString in my previous projects. How can I solve it?

```
public class Student {

    private int id; 
    private String name;
    private Double Gpa;

    public Student(int id, String name, double gpa) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        Gpa = gpa;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public Double getGpa() {
        return Gpa;
    }
    public void setGpa(Double gpa) {
        Gpa = gpa;
    }

}
```

Comment: Looks like you are having issues with your setup. What IDE are you using or how do you invoke the compiler? What tool produces the error message? Did you click a button in your IDE or did you invoke javac from the command line?

Comment: Your problem what you currently have it something to do with your code editor settings. Please provide us more details on that

Comment: You should adhere to the Java Naming Conventions: variable names are always written in camelCase, i.e. `Gpa` should be `gpa`.